# Trying to use INSERT INTO function with no avail

Tags: php, mysql, forms

For something ever so simple, I'm having ongoing issues with. My problem is how can I properly use the INSERT INTO function, into a database? Before I start, I just want to say that I have seen plenty of other examples and yet non have helped.

Before I clarify my problem, I just want to explain the background. Basically have two registration forms, both are used one after the other with their own input devices and validations. When I input the data in the first registration form, I press next and it takes me to the second form where I must fill out other information before I "register" completely. In my second registration form, I used a list of hidden inputs, like `<input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php echo  $_POST['name'];?>"/>` so that I can hold the information from first registration file and still possess the same data without loosing it completely when I am taken to the next registration page.

Anyway, back to my problem, I am simply having trouble trying to insert all the data (from both registration forms) I enter into my database. Below is my attempt at creating a simple INSERT INTO php function hoping it will work, but to no avail.

```
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "name", "psswd"); 
 mysql_select_db("database", $conn) 
 or die ('Database not found ' . mysql_error() ); 

$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
$name=$_POST['name'];
$lname=$_POST['lname'];
$postcode=$_POST['postcode'];
$agreement=$_POST['agreement'];
$conditions=$_POST['conditions'];

$sql= "INSERT INTO table (username, password, name, lname, postcode, agreement, conditions) 
VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$name', '$lname', '$postcode', '$agreement', '$conditions')";

 $rs = mysql_query($sql, $conn) 
 or die ('Problem with query' . mysql_error()); 
 //echo "1 record added";
 mysql_close($conn)
?>
```

I honestly have no clear idea where I have gone wrong. I don't know whether I should have the INSERT INTO functions in both forms or only the second registration form (which is where it is only places at the moment). Or if the php function should be placed in some specific area in my form?

I should also add that when I start up my registration page, it opens but I get errors (or notice) appearing from under my page saying that at each line of my names or fields section (`$username=$_POST['username'];`, etc), I have an 'Undefined index' and another error 'Problem with queryIncorrect integer value: '' for column 'postcode' at row 1'.

I have gone beyond my limit in fixing this and in need for help. All I would like to know is how I can change my code to something that actually functions and sends the data I put into my database?

Comment: Your query is unprotected, a simple `'` will easily break it, if not allowing a direct SQL injection

Comment: Just reading the error message should help `Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'postcode' at row 1'` Currently you're trying to insert an empty string into a numeric field.

Comment: Please read up on SQL injection vulnerabilities, hashed passwords and using PDO or at least mysqli_ instead of mysql_ functions. This is dangerously bad code.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem you seem to be having is that you have no POST data being passed, hence the 'Undefined index' error that you are receiving. var_dump($_POST) to see if you are even getting POST data to the update script.

You might want to also look into Sessions if you have a multiple forms during your registration process to collect the data to insert when the user has completed all forms.